# laravel graphql playground got error when i setup it

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

When setup this package in  lighthouse tutorial I got this error
what I can do now?

https://github.com/mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground

### Composer

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground": "^1.0",
        "nuwave/lighthouse": "^2.6"
    },
```

### Error

```
In Router.php line 363:  
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array, string giv     en,
called in D:\Laravel\lighthouse-tutorial\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\ Facades\Facade.php on line 223
--
In Router.php line 363:  
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type
array, string given, called in D:\Laravel\lighthouse-tutorial\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 223
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with er ror code 1
--
```

### Update

Config file

```
<?php

return [
    // Route for the frontend
    'route' => 'graphql-playground',

    // Which middleware to apply, if any
    'middleware' => [
        // 'web',
    ],

    // Route for the GraphQL endpoint
    'endpoint' => 'graphql',

    // Control if the playground is accessible at all
    // This allows you to disable it completely in production
    'enabled' => env('GRAPHQL_PLAYGROUND_ENABLED', true),
];
```

The problem is here when I remove this is working `'route' => 'graphql-playground',`

Comment: Please show your routes file if possible.

Comment: This is a clean project just in my web router is `url ('/')`

Comment: ```Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});```

Comment: I suspect https://github.com/mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground/issues/24 might be at play

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in `GraphQLPlaygroundServiceProvider.php` they are using route group:

```
Route::group(
    config('graphql-playground.route'),
...
```

but the route group requires an array parameter so I solved the issue by changing the config file from:

```
'route' => 'graphql-playground',
```

to the route as an array:

```
'route' => ['graphql-playground'],
```

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Explained:**

This happened in the lighthouse-tutorial repo when I tried following along I found that it was because the config file is returning a string where an array is expected.

**FIX**

Go to config/graphql-playground.php of the lighthouse-tutorial repo and change 
`'route' => 'graphql-playground'`  to `'route' => ['graphql-playground']`

Then run your `composer require nuwave/lighthouse mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground` again.

This fixed it for me.